# How to revert two commits back and commit only good stuff?

Tags: git

I commited something wrong twice. How to revert two commits back and commit only good stuff ?

Comment: What is the good stuff? Could you describe in more detail how does your history look now and how do you want it to look?

Comment: a little more detail would help if getting the correct answer (good stuff?)

Comment: Delete all the bad stuff before you commit everything else.

Comment: Do you mean just to your local repo or have you pushed aleady?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do a `git rebase -i HEAD~2` and then use the interface to discard the "bad commits" that are there since then and clean up your history. This however alters the project history and if you've already pushed (and others pulled) your changes, there are some social issues to work out.

The other option is to `git revert` those changes. Then 2 new commits will get added to the history that makes the fact that you don't want these two commits explicit in the project history. Less clean but easier to work with.

Comment: My coworkers will complain that the bad commit was ever there to begin with. Better to get rid of it before trying to merge the branch. Thanks for providing the `git rebase -i` answer and not just saying "you don't really want to do that!" like many people do!

Comment: Another useful command in this situation is `git push --force`, in case you've already pushed the bad commit.

Comment: The `--force` option is destructive. If someone else has made changes on top your commits and pushed them to the repository, your force push  will destroy all of them.

Comment: That's why I only use it on my own branches, where that's not an issue (but the bad commits I've pushed *are* an issue). It's especially useful when I make a PR and then the PM says "break all the commits you made to module FOO into their own PR and merge them before the rest of the commits that are interleaved with them."

Answer (score 31):

First, `git reset HEAD~2` to discard the top two commits, while leaving your working tree exactly as it is.
Then, simply create a new commit with what you want (e.g., with `git add`s and then `git commit`).

See [Reset Demystified](https://git-scm.com/blog/2011/07/11/reset.html) by Scott Chacon for the details on the often confusing `git reset` comamnd.

Comment: I would only do this is the commit are local only, if they are public I would use revert on the last 2 commits

Comment: Yes, I was assuming the OP had not pushed the incorrect commits anywhere.

Answer (score 6):

## Revert changes in a new Commit

If you want to completely undo the commits and delete them, use `rebase` or `reset` like other answers suggest.

**But sometimes, you can't modify git history** (for example after pushing to a protected branch on remote). In that case, your best bet is `git revert`:

```sh
git revert --no-commit HEAD~1^..HEAD
```

This will revert all changes in the last two commits (from `HEAD` to `HEAD~1`). You can make sure everything looks good by checking the status or diff and commit the revert:

```sh
git status # or git diff
git commit -m "Reverted the last two commits"
```